# Django rules object permissions

Tags: python, django, permissions, rules

I am trying to use [django rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules#using-rules-with-django) to configure object permissions in django and the django admin interface.

Now when I add permission rules, they will always only be called with the first param, but the object is always None.

For example I if I would create this predicate:

```
@rules.predicate
def is_book_author(user, book):
    return book.author == user
```

And then add it to the django permission set:

```
rules.add_perm('books.view_book', is_book_author)
```

Now when I log into the admin interface with a user, then the is_book_author will be called with the user and None. It will be called multiple times (once per object), but the object ist always None.

I am using rules 2.0.0 with django 2.1.1 and python 3.7.

Any ideas if I'm doing something wrong or how to configure django to call the predicate with the individual object?

Comment: Well at that moment the book does not exists yet. `add_book` is the permission to add a book, not to "save" the book. I think you should handle this in the form (or even in the form just "inject" the user, such that he/she can simply *never* add other data).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I have the problem with all 4 permissions. I replaced  add_book in the question with the view_book permission to clarify.

Comment: @BluE I'm trying to solve your issue but everything works for me just fine. I used testapp to debug it and still cannot reproduce your issue. Could you provide whole files where you use `ObjectPermissionsModelAdmin` and  `add_perm` with predicate?
Take a look also on https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules/blob/v2.0.0/tests/testapp/rules.py
Try to compare your code with that from the repo.

Comment: @KamilNiski I will update the question after work today to add the requested information. Quick question: Were you using the same django version, when you tried the example?

Comment: Yes, I used exactly the same versions of libraries as you specified

Comment: @BluE any news? Were you able to find the problem?

Answer (score 8):

As `django-rules` [documentation](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules#rules-and-permissions-in-the-admin) states:

> Django Admin **does not support object-permissions**, in the sense that it will never ask for permission to perform an action on an object, only whether a user is allowed to act on (any) instances of a model.
>
> If you'd like to tell Django whether a user has permissions on a specific object, you'd have to override the following methods of a model's ModelAdmin:
>
> ```
> has_view_permission(user, obj=None)
> has_change_permission(user, obj=None)
> has_delete_permission(user, obj=None)
> ```
>
> rules comes with a custom `ModelAdmin` subclass, `rules.contrib.admin.ObjectPermissionsModelAdmin`, that overrides these methods to pass on the edited model instance to the authorization backends, thus enabling permissions per object in the Admin:
>
> ```
> # books/admin.py
> from django.contrib import admin
> from rules.contrib.admin import ObjectPermissionsModelAdmin
> from .models import Book
>
> class BookAdmin(ObjectPermissionsModelAdmin):
>     pass
>
> admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
> ```
>
> Now this allows you to specify permissions like this:
>
> ```
> rules.add_perm('books', rules.always_allow)
> rules.add_perm('books.add_book', has_author_profile)
> rules.add_perm('books.change_book', is_book_author_or_editor)
> rules.add_perm('books.delete_book', is_book_author)
> ```
>
> To preserve backwards compatibility, Django will ask for either view or change permission. For maximum flexibility, rules behaves subtly different: rules will ask for the change permission if and only if no rule exists for the view permission.

Comment: I already use the ObjectPermissionsModelAdmin, but as said the object passed is always None. (Otherwise the predicate would not be called at all)

Comment: Please compare your setup with testapp in django-rules repo https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules/blob/master/tests/testapp/rules.py
I'm inspecting the tests that use predicate and i can see book being passed correctly